# Is there a better way to monitor keystrokes than system wide WH_CBT hook?

Tags: winapi, hook, code-injection, setwindowshookex, keylogger

I am currently researching a good reliable way of logging user actions on the computer. I created a simple app that hooks `WH_CBT` events globally and it seems to work fine for now. I've read about situations when an application would've their own `WH_CBT` event handler and would not call `CallNextHookEx()` function after handling it. I assume that scenario would prevent me from handling any events in that application myself with a system wide hook.

Is there any other (maybe better) way to hijack keystroke events in applications? Maybe something related to manually injecting a DLL to processes like this:

1. Pick process.
2. Inject DLL using `CreateRemoteThreadEx()`.
3. DLL hooks (detours) some winapi functions and gathers information from them about keystrokes or other events.

Would hooking `GetMessage()` or `TranslateMessage()` functions be enough in that case? Am I right that any process using a Message Loop would have to use these functions in order to process events for created windows?

Comment: This is a strange kind of paranoia in this question.  Of course you cannot protect yourself against a misbehaving other hooker.  Just as you can't protect yourself against the user removing yours.  She'll leave your code in place and remove others when she has a compelling reason to believe your code is useful.  The more invasive your code, the less likely she'll be convinced.

Comment: You're right. I just wanted to make sure misbehaving hookers is not something common that I should prepare for. Refering to event hooker as a "she" made me smile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A low level keyboard hooking using `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` would be the best (as it would capture everything), but other more specific solutions exist, such as [sub-classing the parent level window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window) of whatever application you targeting to capture the key related window messages, which avoids having to do any code tampering or system wide filtering.

Back to a more global scope, you can also do this using `WH_KEYBOARD`, `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_GETMESSAGE` based hooks, which can be done globally or at thread level. It all depends on what and how much you are trying to capture.